# curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer - when hitting docker container

Tags: networking, docker, curl

From an AWS ec2 instance (which runs `docker`), I am trying to `curl` my docker container-hosted web service.

Given:

```
[ec2-user]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
b56fa0d76d5c        $REGISTRY/$WORK/metrics:v0.1.0   "/bin/sh -c 'sh /root"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   insane_leakey
```

I can hit the web service from within the container:

```
[ec2-user]$ docker exec -it b56fa0d76d5c bash
root@b56fa0d76d5c:/# curl 'http://localhost/health'
Request is missing required query parameter 'apiName'
```

But, I can't hit it from the host:

```
[ec2-user]$ curl 'http://localhost/health'
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I looked at this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349895/409976) on this `curl` error, but I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: I wonder from time to time why this question was closed when it is just perfect.

Comment: Be aware if you're running a VPN this will change localhost/127.0.0.1.  Try disabling your VPN if using one.

Answer (score 30):

Connection Reset to a Docker container usually indicates that you've defined a port mapping for the container that does not point to an application.

So, if you've defined a mapping of 80:80, check that your process inside the docker instance is in fact running on port 80 (netstat -an|grep LISTEN).

You get a reset as the Docker 'proxy' picks up the connection, attempts to connect to the process inside the container, fails, so resets the connection.

Comment: No `netstat` on the container, but I ran: `ss -a | grep -i LIST` to output `tcp    LISTEN     0      100       ::ffff:127.0.0.1:http                 :::*`. If I read that output correctly, then it's listening on `localhost:80`?

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/26553296/409976 fixed my issue, i.e. using `"0.0.0.0"` as the interface, **not** `"localhost"`.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Your solution wasn't an actual fix for me, but it lead me to the issue. This happened to me because the service started on 127.0.0.1:9200 (inside container) and it wasn't "published" because of the IP. So I changed it to 0.0.0.0:9200 and then it started to work from outside of the container. You need to have the 9200 port exposed, but I'm sure you already know that.

Comment: @KevinMeredith : Thanks for that.. been struggling for past 4 hours coz of that!!!

Comment: @KevinMeredith I still can't make it work after changing host to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I've been looking for this for about 2 hours. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: This is correct, I was mapping the host OS port to a port on which an application was not running in the container; got this error. After removing the container and starting with the right port mapping it worked.

Comment: This is such a beautiful answer. 
For some reason, in very simple words, it also gives such a beautiful understanding about the concept behind the problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can investigate this by installing tshark on the container and then do `tshark -i any`:

If you then do a request externally you should see something like the below:

```
root@618910b515f0:/code# tshark -i any
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'any'
tshark: cap_set_proc() fail return: Operation not permitted

tshark: cap_set_proc() fail return: Operation not permitted

    1 0.000000000   172.18.0.1 → 172.18.0.3   TCP 76 45844 → 8001 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=820044004 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000019457   172.18.0.3 → 172.18.0.1   TCP 56 8001 → 45844 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

The network packet came in but it responded with a `RST`, which means it was rejected.

---

Most probably you're listening on `127.0.0.1` rather than `0.0.0.0` - all IPs. You can verify this by running `netstat -tulpn`