# Forward forwarded port in Docker

Tags: networking, docker, ssh-tunnel

I have some trouble forwarding ports that are `LocalForward` to the container via SSH Tunnel.

The whole network looks like this:

[image: Network scheme]

This is my `Dockerfile` for the `GW Container`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y ssh \
  && apt-get clean

EXPOSE 80

COPY config /root/.ssh/config

ENTRYPOINT ["ssh", "app-server", "sleep infinity & wait"]
```

Related ssh `config` file:

```
Host vpn-gateway
 StrictHostKeyChecking no
 UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
 Hostname 10.20.30.40
 User matrix

Host app-server
 StrictHostKeyChecking no
 UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
 Hostname 20.30.40.50
 User matrix
 ProxyCommand ssh vpn-gateway nc %h %p %r
 LocalForward 80 30.40.50.60:1080
```

Now, I am using `docker-compose` for container orchestration with the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  gateway:
      container_name: gateway
      image: gateway
      build: ./docker/gateway
      volumes:
          - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
          - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      ports:
        - 8080:80
```

So, the idea is that if I run wget from localhost:
`wget http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/health` I will get a response from the `API Server` machine (`30.40.50.60:1080`). The problem is that I get reset:

```
--2018-06-25 07:19:26--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/health
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2018-06-25 07:19:27--  (try: 2)  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/health
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

This could be caused by Docker not seeing any app using port 80 on the `GW Container` as mentioned here: https://serverfault.com/a/769583/292211

If I `exec` to the `GW Container` and run `wget http://127.0.0.1:80/api/health` I am getting a proper response.

Is there a way to cheat docker into thinking port 80 is available in the `GW Container` so it would allow me to forward port to the host? Or could any of these things be handled in a better way? All the mumbo-jumbo with SSH tunnels is due to third-party security restrictions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that the LocalForward bind address is localhost by default.

In order for arbitrary external connections to be accepted, you could try:

```
Host app-server    
    LocalForward 0.0.0.0:80 30.40.50.60:1080
```