# Active internet connections returned by netstat -an is blank inside docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I am new to the concept of dockers and containers. So sorry if I frame the question in a wrong way. The issue is -

An aws EC2 instance which is running docker is failing load balancer health checks. I tired to curl docker container hosted web service from the instance and it returned `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`
I went through this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/769578/curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-when-hitting-docker-container?newreg=dd808e8165444c3ea3b35a5a66a32487)

As suggested in the answer I used `netstat -an|grep LISTEN` from within the container and it didn't return anything (No error. The control just went to next line returning nothing).

I have no clue what to do right now. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml and the command you run to spin up the containers?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that nothing really listens on that port. Is your container actually running the service you want it to run? Does `ps ax` from inside the running container show the process you expect? (e.g. `httpd` or `nginx` or whatwever you expect to listen on that port?)

Make sure your `Dockerfile` has the appropriate `EXPOSE {port}`, `RUN {command}` and/or `CMD ...` statements. That will ensure that 1) the command you want is actually started and 2) the port it listens on is exposed to the outside world.

Comment: I want my container to run nginx and ps ax shows that nginx is running

Comment: @sdy_159 post your `Dockerfile`